# iOS - Get notified about user 3G connection even when he is connected to WiFi

Tags: ios, reachability

From some reason I need to track the 3G/4G... connectivity even if the user is connected to WiFi.
I can not do that using Rateability as :

- It does not notify on change if I turn the 3G off while user has active WiFi.
- When connected to WiFi `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN` is false even if the user did not disable the Cellular connection.

Is that possible ?
Thanks